# Openshift not installing node modules

Tags: node.js, openshift-online-2, npm

I have a production pipeline of local code pushed via git to Wercker (a continuous delivery platform) and then is forwarded to openshift for production. Both steps, the local build and the deployment to openshift give no errors but when the code builds again on openshift it doesn't install all of my dependencies. I've seen this question posted quite a bit but each answer seemed to have some strange variable that didn't apply and I'm either too knew to extract the answer or they aren't actually hitting my problem.

How do I get openshift to install all the darn dependencies? Thanks!

Comment: changing home to `HOME=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` would work!